# Open URL from button action in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I am retrieving an URL from a parse.com Object.

I want to open the device's browser and show the URL received from Parse when the user clicks on the button.

This is the action:

```
  @IBAction func botonNuevos(sender: AnyObject) {

        let query = PFQuery(className: "datos_contacto")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("H52ZxGm3U8", block: {
            (questionObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            let webNuevos: AnyObject! = questionObject!.valueForKey("dato_contacto")

            print(webNuevos) //= http://www.touchemotors.com

            if let webCallURL = NSURL(string: webNuevos as! String ) {
                let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
                if application.canOpenURL(webCallURL) {
                    application.openURL(webCallURL)
                }
                else{
                    print("failed")
                }
            }


        })
    }
```

when the button is clicked, the log shows the received URL, but the browser is not launched and any error is shown.

Please tell what is wrong in my code. Thank you

Comment: I test you're code and everything is working fine.Show questionObject!.valueForKey("dato_contacto") value of this object.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk, I have included it as comment after print(webNuevos), the received value of the object is: http://www.touchemotors.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Finally after discussion with OP it turned out that value returned by `questionObject!.objectForKey("dato_contacto")` had whitespace at the end so `NSUrl(string:)` did not parse it well.

**UPDATE**

You are using wrong method `NSObject.valueForKey()`. Use `PFObject.objectForKey()` instead.

**For iOS 9**:

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:):

> If your app is linked on or after iOS 9.0, you must declare the URL
>   schemes you want to pass to this method. Do this by using the
>   LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array in your Xcode project’s Info.plist
>   file. For each URL scheme you want your app to use with this method,
>   add it as a string in this array.
>
> If your (iOS 9.0 or later) app calls this method using a scheme you
>   have not declared, the method returns false, whether or not an
>   appropriate app for the scheme is installed on the device.

Add `http` scheme to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` array in `Info.plist`.

Comment: Thank you @mixel. If I write an URL directly in the line if let webCallURL = NSURL(string: webNuevos as! String ) instead of the variable webNuevos, then everything works. The browser is launched and the URL shown.

Comment: I think I found reason you getting this error. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @mixel, but using objectForKey() or valueForKey() I get the same result for webNuevos: http://www.touchemotors.com and also the same behaviour, browser not launched

Comment: Does `let urlString = PFObject.objectForKey("dato_contacto") as? String` evaluate to `nil`?

Comment: It throws an error in XCode:  "Cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type PFObject.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `let urlString = questionObject!.objectForKey("dato_contacto") as? String`.

Comment: Thanks, let me check it

Comment: I get this output for your line: Optional("http://www.touchemotors.com "), including the http:// part, not shown here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100652/discussion-between-mixel-and-mvasco).

Comment: I have improved my code with @mixel answer, but the issue was a white space at the end of the received string from parse